# Roulette game hangs on while loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to get this `while` loop to keep playing a roulette game until my budget is empty. When I run the code it just hangs. 
Here is the `while` code including the loop that hangs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
    }

    protected void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        int Budget = Convert.ToInt32(txtMyBudget.Text);
        int Bet = Convert.ToInt32(txtMyBet.Text);
        int Outcome = Convert.ToInt32(txtMyNum.Text);

        //generates a random number between 0 and 38
        Random num = new Random();

        int numSpun = num.Next(0, 38);
        lblBudgetError.Text = numSpun.ToString();

        //checks to make sure the budget is set
        if (txtMyBudget.Text == "")
        {
            lblBudgetError.Text = "Please set your budget";
        }

        int myBudget = Budget;           
        while (Budget >= Bet)
        {
            myBudget++;    
          lblValidate.Text += myBudget.ToString() + "<br />";                

            if (numSpun == Outcome)
            {
                int newBudget = Bet * 35 + Budget;
                txtMyBudget.Text = newBudget.ToString();    
            }
            else
            {   
                int newBudget = Budget - Bet;
                txtMyBudget.Text = newBudget.ToString();    
            }    
        }        
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where's the **loop**?

Comment: You have no clue of what you are doing and you expect somebody else to solve it for you?

Comment: Yes, I am very new at this and I am struggling. How else is one suppose to learn? I thought that this is what this site is for to help people learn. Not once did I ask for the code. I asked so people can tell me what I am doing wrong and guide me on what I should be doing differently. I am sorry we are not all expert coders like you bc004346.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the `myBudget` not `Budget` which is used in the loop. Either change the condition (use `myBudget`, like `while (myBudget >= Bet)`) or increase the `Budget`.

BTW, if you come from a background with two-way binding, it is not the case here, i.e., changing the value of the `TextBox` doesn't change the value of the `Budget` and you should update its value, for example in a getter.